# SharePoint lookup does not contain several of my columns

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 like this:

```
Contractor (people or group)
Vendor (lookup)
phone number
notes
```

I have another list

```
PO number (text)
Contractor (lookup)
```

I want to select the contractor name from the first list. Column does not display as an item I can pick from. It also does not display Vendor.

I tried adding other colunns with people or group.. doesnt display those either.

Please help!

Comment: This is probably better asked on [sharepoint.se]

Comment: dont know how to do that

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment, sign up and ask, exactly as you did here.